# How to listen available debug targets change in change chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm building a Chrome extension. I've got all targets by the method of `chrome.debugger.getTargets`, and I want to listen this targets change event.then I found [Target.setDiscoverTargets](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-setDiscoverTargets), so I try to use following code.

```js
chrome.debugger.attach({ extensionId: chrome.runtime.id }, "1.3", () => {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ extensionId: chrome.runtime.id }, "Target.setDiscoverTargets", { discover: true });
})
```

But I got an error message.

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: {"code":-32000,"message":"Not allowed"}`

Can somebody tell me why this command not allowed, is the target of sendCommand first params error or
don't chrome extension support this method?

Comment: What is the point of attaching to your own extension? It won't work I guess as a process can't debug itself.